# Where is my bash arithmetic error?

Tags: bash

I am attempting to run the following bash script on boot (from /etc/rc.local) but the script does not get run because of the following syntax error:

```
+1") syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ''
```

Here is the script in full

```
#!/bin/bash
distro=$(cat /etc/issue | head -n 2 | tr -d "\n" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")
device=$(fdisk -l | grep -w 8e | head -n 1 | cut -c-8)
partcount=$(fdisk -l | grep $device | sed 1d | grep -c $device)
newpartnum=$(($partcount+1))
startsector=$(fdisk -l | grep -w 8e | tail -1 | tr " " "\n" | sed "/^$/d" | head -n 3 | tail -1)
newstartsector=$(($startsector+1))
endsector=$(fdisk -l | grep sectors | head -n 1 | tr " " "\n" | tail -2 | head -n 1)
newendsector=$(($endsector-1))
fdisk $device <<EOF
n
p
$newpartnum
$newstartsector
$newendsector
t
$newpartnum
8e
w
EOF

sed -i'.bak' '/00resize/d' /etc/rc.local
echo "sh /root/01setup.sh" >> /etc/rc.local

#reboot
```

I assume the error is with $(($partcount+1)) or $(($startsector+1)) but I'm not sure how.

Comment: `set -x` is your friend here. Put it on the line after `#!/bin/bash` and check that values of your variables are what you expect. Also, http://shellcheck.net will highlight some common errors.

Comment: Suggested alternative syntax: `(( newpartnum = partcount + 1 ))`. Much easier to read that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you have introduced one or more <kbd>CR</kbd> codes by editing your bash script on Windows. Try running the script through `dos2unix` and see if the problem disappears.

(If you don't have `dos2unix`, you can try `tr -d \\r <script >newscript`)